# How to insert text into a file

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do I insert a string at the beginning of a text file using batch? Would it be possible to do so without creating a temp or a new file?

I am currently merging two files using copy, but that is very inefficient since my files are several GB big.

I would like to do something like `copy "string1"+file1 file1`

Thanks!

Comment: Hypothetically it is possible to prepend content to a file without copying anything on-disk, simply by adding a new disk-cluster and declaring the new cluster is the start of the file and then setting the next-cluster link (of the new cluster) to the old first-cluster. This requires low-level filesystem access, however.

Comment: @Dai, obviously this would work only for cluster-sized strings.

Comment: @wOxxOm No, clusters don't have to be filled so it can be shorter, and if it's longer then just allocate new clusters before linking to the original.

Comment: I note that my approach doesn't work if the file has a Unicode BOM (or any other kind of header or prefix), or else ensure any reader will ignore the BOM as they read the file.

Comment: @Dai, that applies only to the last cluster, not the first or any intermediate.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm sorry but I don't understand the point you're trying to make.

Comment: @Dai, the point is that your idea won't work for arbitrary-sized strings. Only the last cluster of a file can be filled less than 100%.

Comment: @Dai, also you may want to delete your comments after the first one after reading some in-depth article about Windows NTFS file system. On the other hand I'd be very pleasantly surprised if you can name *any* file system that may have clusters of arbitrary size with *byte* granularity except for the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't avoid copying when inserting text in the beginning of a file.

The only thing you can do to speedup the process in case your file is on a conventional HDD drive (not SSD) is copy it to a *different local physical drive* (preferably a faster one), then move the file back.

```
>tmp.txt echo Some text
copy /b tmp.txt + bigfile d:\another_physical_drive\file.tmp
del tmp.txt
move /y d:\another_physical_drive\file.tmp bigfile
```

It works on HDDs because sequential write or read speed is 10 times higher (or even much more) than frequent seeking-reading-seeking-writing (also called disk-thrashing) when copying within the same physical drive using the built-in commands. Only some rare 3rd-party utilities are smart and can read in very big chunks filling the RAM up to 50% for example, then do an unbuffered write to skip OS caching, thus essentially always doing a sequential access.

Comment: Why would the fact that it is another physical drive be a benefit? (Unless you _want_ it slower)

Comment: @StefanBormann, because on hard drives (which still are used more than SSD, especially for large files) sequential write speed is 10 times higher (or more) than seeking-reading-seeking-writing when copying on the same physical drive. Some rare utilities are smart and can read in very big chunks filling the RAM up to 50% for example, then do an unbuffered write to skip OS caching, but the built-in utilities don't do that.

Comment: but moving in the same drive is O(1), moving accross drives is essentially another copy with O(n)

Comment: @StefanBormann, the pure mathematics doesn't account for the extremely slow seeking on the conventional hard drives. This was the entire point of my lengthy explanation.

Comment: Well, anyway, thanks for the question, the answer lacked an explanation and I've updated it now.

Comment: Your solution writes the entire results twice, once to a fast temp drive, and once to an allegedly slow main drive. It is much faster to simply write the temporary file directly to the final main location, and then use MOVE to nearly instantaneously rename the temp file to overwrite the original. This still writes the file once to the slow drive, but bypasses the need to also write it to the fast drive.

Comment: @dbenham, my solution avoids disk-thrashing due to slow HDD-seeking if doing everything within the same physical drive, which can slow down the process several times. I thought I've explained it clear enough... Of course if there is enough RAM and no need to process a lot of huge files it's okay to do it using the same folder.

Comment: OK, it took a while, but I understand the issue now. It is counter intuitive, but I can see how your design can improve performance in some situations. I wonder what impact a striped RAID configuration might have. I can envision how RAID might be able to minimize thrashing on logically in place copies if the read and write are always (or frequently) on different physical drives. Such a configuration might be the best of both worlds.

Comment: Well, an average PC has 4-8GB of RAM, the file cache is 256MB-1GB, and maybe only in half of cases an SSD is used for the storage. So I'd say in about ~50% of situations my solution would be faster. And in case we only look at HDDs the percentage would be higher.

Comment: Also, you are assuming exclusive use of the disk resource. A busy shared network resource might be thrashing no matter what you do.

Comment: What network resource? I only meant local physical drives. I'll add that clarification into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to avoid writing the entire result to disk. I would use the following:

```
>"bigfile.txt.new" ( echo Some text&type "bigfile.txt" )
move /y "bigfile.txt.new" "bigfile.txt" >nul
```

The important thing is that the MOVE is nearly instantaneous, and it is a single operation that is equivalent to deleting the original file and then renaming the temp to the original name.

Comment: This is prone to disk-thrashing unlike using a different physical drive: as you can see in [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) the system reads in extremely small chunks and immediately writes each chunk hundreds times per second: http://puu.sh/kFhlR/f74b40430a.png To cache the entire 1GB file in write cache the PC would need a lot of *free* RAM because Windows limits the percentage of memory allocated for cache. This means that after a while every read operation will be interspersed with HDD-seeking and a write operation (disk-thrashing).